# OneSignal problem, multiple commands produce

Tags: onesignal

I have this problem using OneSignalFramework:
Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce '/Users/username/Documents/cimaApp/cimaapp/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalExtension.framework'

Before I had this problem, I had another one which told me that I could not find the oneSignal framework, then I installed it following the official documentation and I got the new error.

Comment: Encountering a similar error, have you addressed it yet?